# using default browser behaviour for href and target in an <a> tag in angular2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, angular2-routing

In angular2, how do you implement the behavior of a simple

```
<a href="some url" target="_whatever">
```

without the routing module highjacking the url with the [base href](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#base-href)?

For example, expected behaviour for the following snippet in an angular template would be to open google in a new tab.

```
<a href="www.google.com" target="_blank">
```

What actually happens is angular compiles the template as follows.

```
<a _ngcontent-kju-6="" target="_blank" ng-reflect-href="www.google.com" href="www.google.com">
```

Clicking on this opens **[the base url]**/www.google.com a new tab rather than simply www.google.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prefixing your url with a protocol should give you what you want, e.g. 'http://www.google.com'.